# How to setOnClickListener on a positiveButton in AlertDialog?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-alertdialog

I created alertDialog with EditText where user types in a comment and positiveButton that shows a Toast.

I would like the comment to be saved in SharedPreferences.

How do I add setOnClickListener on a positive button?

Thanks!

Alert dialog looks like this:

fun addNote(view: View) {

```
    val positiveButtonClick = { dialog: DialogInterface, which: Int ->
        Toast.makeText(this, "Comment saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}
    
    val negativeButtonClick = { dialog: DialogInterface, which: Int ->}

    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    val inflater =layoutInflater
    val dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_edit_text, null)


    with(builder)
    {
        setMessage("Comment")
        setView(dialogLayout)
        setPositiveButton("CONFIRM",DialogInterface.OnClickListener(positiveButtonClick))
        setNegativeButton("CANCEL", DialogInterface.OnClickListener(negativeButtonClick))
        show()
    }
}
```

Comment: You already have your setOnClickListener with your 'positiveButtonClick' event. Instead of only defining your Toast in there, you can also add your savePreferences in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am editing my answer based on your comment below:
replace all this:

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
val inflater =layoutInflater
val dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_edit_text, null)


with(builder)
{
    setMessage("Comment")
    setView(dialogLayout)
    setPositiveButton("CONFIRM",DialogInterface.OnClickListener(positiveButtonClick))
    setNegativeButton("CANCEL", DialogInterface.OnClickListener(negativeButtonClick))
    show()
}
```

with this:

```
    val dialogLayout = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.comment_edit_text, null)

    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setView(dialogLayout)
        .show()
    
    builder.myButton.setOnClickListener { 
        
    }
    builder.setOnDismissListener { 
        
    }
```

"myButton" is the id of your button in the comment_edit_text layout.

As for the message and title ans stuff, just go to your comment_edit_text layout and add textViews and stuff for your message and make it beautiful. it will all be inflated into your AlertDialog.

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. But now, in the builder I added setView(myCustomLayout) with EditText and I keep getting NullPointerException after clicking positiveButton. I tried findViewById that EditText but Logcat says "must not be null". Do you know how to access that EditText from another layout file?

Comment: I edited my answer for a custom layout being inflated into the AlertDialog. check it out. The reason for your NPE is that you must access your views in an AlertDialog through the dialog instance not independently.

Comment: Thanks for that. I did that and it led me towards final solution. In the end, my biggest problem was accessing the EditText in the layout to save String in Shared preferences. I kept using EditText.text.toString() but that EditText was coming out as null because I didn't address the dialog. I used:

val builder = AlertDialog.Builder
val insertedName = builder.editTextComment.text.toString()

and problem is solved. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score -1):

Please do some research on your question before posting it on stack overflow, you can do it like this.

```
setPositiveButton("CONFIRM"){ dialog, which -> 
  //Do your post event work here
}
```

Sample code is here https://www.journaldev.com/309/android-alert-dialog-using-kotlin

Comment: OP already has a working onClickListener and instead they're asking how to save values into shared prefs, while the question title and some of the content is misleading, this doesn't answer the question and, if you feel a question hasn't done research, it's best to not answer it

Comment: Sorry but your getting it wrong please carefully look at the OP question's description 'How do I add setOnClickListener on a positive button?' And also the title says it all, the first query he's asking is how to set listener on a dialog positive button!

Comment: `val positiveButtonClick = { dialog: DialogInterface, which: Int ->
        Toast.makeText(this, "Comment saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}`  and

`setPositiveButton("CONFIRM",DialogInterface.OnClickListener(positiveButtonClick)`

this is code found in OP's question, so they clearly know how to set the click listener